# Woocommerce get product Size in Email Template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a email template and I am trying to get the size of the product. I have tried the following, but it retrieves all the sizes:

```
echo nl2br( $_product->get_attribute( 'size' ) );
```

The code above did work for `color`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Your question is not clear about the problem. You should add few more
>   details, "are you trying to do outside of woocommerce loop?" and "are
>   you getting any error message?"

Anyway, you can get any custom attributes value by following code:

`$product->get_attribute( 'your_attr' );`

If your products custom attribute name is `size`, you can use as following:

```
global $product;
echo nl2br( $product->get_attribute( 'size' ) );
```

It should work. Thank you.

Comment: Never mind I just figured it out. Posted this question too soon.